# SQL Server, Is null case-sensitive?

Tags: sql-server-2005

A co-worker of mine stated that she have a query that "work" only if she use `NULL`, and not with `null`.

She wasn't able to provide me with an example.

As far as I know there shouldn't be any difference, I even ran a simple test:

```
select case when NULL is NULL then 1 else 0 end;

select case when NULL is null then 1 else 0 end;

select case when null is NULL then 1 else 0 end;

select case when null is null then 1 else 0 end;
```

and, as expected, they all returned `1`.

So here the question, there is any know istance where using `null` is different than using `NULL`?

Comment: SQL is not case sensitive at all. If you compare strings the case _can make_ a difference.

Comment: Its really hard to say that why your co worker said so, but as far as `NULL` and `null` are concerned. It is the same.

Answer (score 3):

maybe she compared strings `'NULL'` and `'null'`

Answer (score 1):

No, `Null` is not case-sensitive. `is NULL` and `is null` will always produce the same result.

Answer (score 0):

It's not a string. It's a keyword in a language that is not case sensitive at all, and that keyword refers to the same singular concept regardless of what case you use.